# Sending a sideoutput when numRecordsOutPerSecond is equal to 0 in KeyedProcessFunction in Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, metrics, flink-cep

Could really appreciate some help on this.

I want to implement a use-case where a KeyedProcessFunction sends a "done" signal when it's numRecordsInPerSecond is equal to 0. The problem is I cannot seem to access this metric out-of-the box. Here's a code snippet of roughly what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public static class MyKeyedProcessFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>, String> {
    private final OutputTag<String> outputTag;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {}

    public MyKeyedProcessFunction(OutputTag<String> outputTag) {
        this.outputTag = outputTag;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void processElement(Tuple2<String, Integer> value, Context ctx, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        // Emit to side output if numRecordsInPerSecond is 0
        double numRecordsInPerSecond = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().getIOMetricGroup().getNumRecordsInPerSecond();
        if (numRecordsInPerSecond == 0) {
            ctx.output(outputTag, "done");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Is it even possible for my flink program to access numRecordsInPerSecond for each operator? I know this metric is available in the WEBUI and can be made available externally but what about internally accessing it in the same Flink job?

Flink Version: 1.17.2

Comment: I think you have to use the REST API (which is what the Web UI does) to get this metric, since it's sent via internal Flink code to the Job Manager.

But I think you need to ask a better question, one more like "I want to do X, what are some options", where "X" in this case seems to be "I want to know when I've consumed all records from some source, and thus can generate a final result".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kkrugler pointed out, accessing metrics from within the job itself isn't straightforward -- there's no API for that.

But from within a `KeyedProcessFunction` you have everything you need to calculate the number of events being processed each second. You can arrange for a processing time timer to fire every second, and maintain the counter yourself.